# Artemis - How to avoid TransactionRolledBackException for Non-Transactional session

Tags: activemq-artemis

I use live/backup with shared-storage, and I use a non-transacted JMS session. I always send one message, and I always receive one message then acknowledge and receive second message only after successful first acknowledge.

I got this exception in my non-transacted session:

```
Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [javax.jms.TransactionRolledBackException - AMQ219030: The transaction was rolled back on failover to a backup server]
javax.jms.TransactionRolledBackException: AMQ219030: The transaction was rolled back on failover to a backup server
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.rollbackOnFailover(ClientSessionImpl.java:904)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.commit(ClientSessionImpl.java:927)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessage.acknowledge(ActiveMQMessage.java:719)
```

It happens because the session was marked as "**rollbackOnly**". I got this state after the following steps:

1. I use Spring-JMS. Consumer session works 24/7 (infinite loop `session.receive()`)
2. The Master Node crashed, then the Master node was restarted
3. After recovery (After a couple of hours), I sent a message to the queue. The consumer read the message and throw Exception on acknowledge(because was marked as rollback-only)
4. I read message again (this is not very bad for my task) but Redelivery Count has not been increased
5. My consumer code:

```java
onMessage(Message message) {
  if (redeliveryCount(message) > 0){
    processAsDublicate(message);  // It's not invoked  - it is error in my business logic.
  }
}
```

6. I migrated from another broker and and I thought not to change the client logic

Question:

How to avoid TransactionRolledBackException for Non-Transactional session? If this is not possible i should change consumer code?

Thank you in Advance

**UPDATE AFTER ANSWER**:

https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/2.14.0/examples/features/ha/replicated-failback

This example is not suitable for my case - I don't have non-acknowledged messages. I got this state after the following steps: 1) Restart server 2) consume message 3) acknoledge message

1. We use a broker for ~30 applications (24/7) ~ 200 consumers in total
2. For example, on the weekend we restart the JMS Broker
3. Will all consumers start getting this exception after consume new messages
   (They don't have non-acknowledged messages)

Answer (score 0):

The TransactionRolledBackException is expected as you can see in the [replicated-failback example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/2.14.0/examples/features/ha/replicated-failback).

To prevent a consumer from receiving the same message more times, an idempotent consumer must be implemented, ie Apache Camel provides an Idempotent consumer component that would work with any JMS provider, see: http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html